# Why shouldn't this offensive line be removed?

Tags: discussion, questions

There's this offensive line

> Is it because the mangakas are lazy, or is there another reason behind this?

in

[Why is anime produced faster than manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19930/why-is-anime-produced-faster-than-manga)

I proposed it be removed, but it wasn't.

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70303

Why?

Comment: You're being nitpicky here. While it can be considered curt, there is no reason to consider it offensive.

Comment: @кяαzєя Would you be offended if someone asked 'Is it because the moderators of anime SE are lazy, or is there another reason behind this?' ?

Comment: We are lazier and tend to have a more laissez faire approach than most other moderators on the network. We're a recreational site, much less prominent and prestigious than out other more well known sister sites, so we don't take ourselves as seriously as the others do and neither should you.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would not consider the use of the word 'lazy' in this context offensive. The OP has a perceived preconception of what might be the cause, and are trying to validate whether this is valid, or another reason is the cause. Hence it can be considered a post criticizes somebody or something in a civil manner.

By not just removing the term 'lazy' but removing the whole phrase together, the context of the question itself gets changed, which will lead to different answers as the implied perception is not taken into account anymore. Hence:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.`

Potentially the sentence could be rephrased to not use the term 'lazy', however the negative perceived preconception the OP has in this scenario wouldn't change.

It is however worth while to point out that the term 'lazy' can be considered offensive if used as a personal attack/name calling. This would be against the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct), at which point you should not just edit it out, but instead flag it as `Rude or Abusive`.

You can also refer to [When to flag something as rude or abusive? (formerly known as offensive )](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/259147) to get a bit more context about when and why to flag a post as Rude or Abusive.